# What is the default value for Panel.ZIndex? (WPF)

Tags: wpf

Short question, as I didn't found this information in the Microsoft documentation ([Panel.ZIndex Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.zindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_Panel_ZIndex)).

The documentation says, that *"Members of a Children collection that have equal ZIndex values are rendered in the order in which they appear in the visual tree."*. Ok, so far everything clear and intuitive.

But what is the default value for Panel.ZIndex?

I assume it is zero, cause my layout seems to behave like that. But I hate surprises in future when making changes to the layout and would like to know it for sure therefore.
Also I don't know if all controls are treated identically, regarding the z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Panel.cs,36940a49fc5219d0), the default value is 0.

```
private const int c_zDefaultValue = 0;              //  default ZIndexProperty value

public static readonly DependencyProperty ZIndexProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "ZIndex",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Panel),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        c_zDefaultValue,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(OnZIndexPropertyChanged)));
```

Comment: Just found out that a `WindowsFormsHost` element ignores the ZIndex and is displayed on top always...

Comment: @Nicolas, `WindowsFormsHost` is a different story. WinForms components are _always_ displayed on-top in an interop app, because WinForms controls use GDI+ for drawing, not DirectX as WPF does.

Comment: This is good to know, so any trials with the ZIndex can be aborted then for the `WindowsFormsHost` control - I solved it with toggling the visibility.